# openpyxl insert top row and update Name Manager

Tags: python, openpyxl

When inserting a row at the top of a spreadsheet, how do I get the Name Manager to add the row to the defined names where the defined names are for each column?

The first row is the header so I am using:

ws.insert_rows(2)

Initially names are defined in the Name Manager for each column for example:

Name          Refers To

_Sample_Id    =Sample!$A$2:$A$2
Description   =Sample!$B$2:$B$2

Where Sample is the name of the sheet

So after I insert the row and populate the cells I want the Name Manager to be updated to:

Name          Refers To

_Sample_Id    =Sample!$A$2:$A$3
Description   =Sample!$B$2:$B$3

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Background:

We are using openpyxl successfully to scrape data from scientist workbooks and to also create scientist workbooks from a template and autofill upstream data. The data may be a simple spreadsheet with a unique key and multiple columns. The columns in this simple spread sheet are accessed by name using the Name Manager. Currently in the Name Manager the size of the defined name is fixed and the addition of a new row is either done manually or using code that doesn't use the Name Manager and is specific to the given spreadsheet. This works fine but the fixed size is problematic as rows are added. I wrote generic code to insert a row at the top of the spreadsheet and populate the columns. This works but did not increase the range of the defined names in the Name Manager.

Comment: Like everything else with Openpyxl if you insert or delete a rows or columns, references like defined names are not automatically updated since it's just updating the xml. Again if you used Xlwings since that uses Excel to make the insert or deletion it will update the references. Seems based on your description that you may be tied to Openpyxl but just be aware it may not only be defined names that are affected, also things like formulas and merged cells so if these are a factor it may still be easier to use Xlwings just to do the insert.

Comment: Actually in hind-sight Xlwings probably wouldn't help you since you have a single cell defined name `Sample!$A$2` or `Sample!$A$2:$A$2`. If you insert a new row at row 2 it would just push that defined name down 1 row so it becomes `Sample!$A$3` or `Sample!$A$3:$A$3`. So for what have specified you want to achieve, manually manipulating the range may be your only option.

Answer (score 0):

To do specifically what you want you can view the following code example.

**However** this example does only what you've indicated; inserting 1 or more rows at `insert_row` (row 2) which is within the single cell defined range given.
**Note** the 'Refers to' range would usually be saved with a single co-ordinate

```
=Sample2!$A$2
```

rather than with a start and end co-ordinate

```
=Sample2!$A$2:$A$2
```

The code will manage either format.

It does not manage

1. Inserting the row before the defined range where both the start and end range values would need to change.
2. Other defined ranges after the row insert

The code updates the defined range value, comment and description fields. In this case the description field is the same as value so `Sample!$A$2:$A$X`, I'm not sure why your details state this is should be

```
Description =Sample!$B$2:$B$2
```

using column 'B' rather than 'A' but that can be relatively easily changed if it needs to be 'B' or something else.

There is no scope mentioned, the code sample will check both Workbook and Worksheet.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range import CellRange
from openpyxl.utils.cell import absolute_coordinate


def increment_range(rng):
    ### Create new range for the defined name
    range_adjust = CellRange(rng)
    range_adjust.expand(down=rows_to_add)

    return f"{range_adjust.title}!{absolute_coordinate(range_adjust.coord)}"


xl_file = 'foo.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(xl_file)
ws = wb['Sample']

### Row to make the insert (fixed)
insert_row = 2

### Defined name to be changed
name_defined = '_Sample_Id'

### Rows to insert at insert_row (variable)
rows_to_add = 1
print(f"Inserting {rows_to_add} rows at row {insert_row}")
ws.insert_rows(insert_row, rows_to_add)
print("-------------------------------------------------")
### Look in Workbook and Worksheet defined names
for excel_obj in [ws, wb]:
    for defined_name in excel_obj.defined_names:
        ### Only apply to the set defined name
        if not defined_name == name_defined:
            continue
        defname_details = excel_obj.defined_names[defined_name]
        object_type = str(type(excel_obj))

        ### Print Defined name state before change
        print(f"Found Defined Name: {defined_name} "
              f"in scope {object_type.split('.')[1]}\n"
              f"Range: {defname_details.value}\n"
              f"Description: {defname_details.description}\n")

        def_range = defname_details.value

        ### Create new range based on the number of rows added
        new_defname_range = increment_range(def_range)

        ### Update the defined name range comment and desctiption fields
        defname_details.value = new_defname_range
        defname_details.comment = new_defname_range
        defname_details.description = new_defname_range

        ### Print Defined name state after change
        print(f"Updated Defined Name: {defined_name} "
              f"in scope {object_type.split('.')[1]}\n"
              f"Range: {defname_details.value}\n"
              f"Description: {defname_details.description}\n")

    print("-------------------------------------------------")

wb.save(xl_file)
```

Comment: Did not see that the tokeniser does much with ranges.

Comment: Look at the translate funtion. Otherwise use a CellRange (or Multi) object which has the relevant methods.  Don't roll your own regexes for this kind of thing.